# How to extract dependency relations (dependency grammer) between POS tags?

Tags: python, nlp, dependencies

Currently, I am working on a project and need some ideas to solve it.
I am thinking of implementing a dependency relation extractor by myself, so it can show if there is a dependency relation between two POS tags. In previous steps, I have implemented a technique using word co-occurrence to group words based on their syntactic roles. For example, Nouns are gathered in the same group and are labeled with 1, or verbs are grouped in group 2 and their label is 2, adverbs are in Group 3, etc.

In reality, there is a dependency relation between noun and verbs, or between verbs and adverbs, or dependency between noun and adjective, but there is not any dependency between noun and adverb or between verb and adjective.

So I want to use POS-tags Co-Occurrences or any other technique to show that there is a dependency relation between Group 1 and Group 2 (between noun group and verb group) and do the same to the other groups. In other words, I am not trying to construct a dependency tree between words, I am trying to just study between which of the detected syntactic groups there are dependency relations.

I would be so thankful if you give my mind to starting this project.